# Does scipy's minimize function with method "COBYLA" accept bounds?

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using the algorithm `'COBYLA'` in scipy's `optimize.minimize` function (v.0.11 build for cygwin). I observed that the parameter `bounds` seems not to be used in this case. For instance, the simple example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return -sum(x)

minimize(f, x0=1, method='COBYLA', bounds=(-2,2))
```

returns:

```
status: 2.0
nfev: 1000
maxcv: 0.0
success: False
fun: -1000.0
x: array(1000.0)
message: 'Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.'
```

instead of the expected `2` for `x`.

Did anyone perceived the same problem? Is there a known bug or documentation error? In the scipy 0.11 documentation, this option is not excluded for the **COBYLA** algorithm. In fact the function `fmin_cobyla` doesn't have the `bounds` parameter. 
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Sounds like it should work, but maybe you have to use `bounds=[(-2,2)]`. I don't have a new scipy with minimize to try though.

Answer (score 14):

You can formulate the bounds in the form of constraints

```
import scipy
#function to minimize
def f(x):
    return -sum(x)
#initial values
initial_point=[1.,1.,1.]    
#lower and upper bound for variables
bounds=[ [-2,2],[-1,1],[-3,3]   ]

#construct the bounds in the form of constraints
cons = []
for factor in range(len(bounds)):
    lower, upper = bounds[factor]
    l = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, lb=lower, i=factor: x[i] - lb}
    u = {'type': 'ineq',
         'fun': lambda x, ub=upper, i=factor: ub - x[i]}
    cons.append(l)
    cons.append(u)

#similarly aditional constrains can be added

#run optimization
res = scipy.optimize.minimize(f,initial_point,constraints=cons,method='COBYLA')
#print result
print res
```

Note that the minimize function will give the design variables to the function. In this case 3 input variables are given with 3 upper and lower bounds. the result yields:

```
   fun: -6.0
   maxcv: -0.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    nfev: 21
  status: 1
 success: True
       x: array([ 2.,  1.,  3.])
```

Answer (score 5):

The original *COBYLA(2)* FORTRAN algorithm does not support variable bounds explicitly, you have to formulate the bounds in the context of the general constraints.

Looking at the current source code for the *SciPy* `minimize` interface [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py), it is apparent that no measures has yet been taken in *SciPy* to handle this limitation.

Thus, in order to apply *bounds* for the *cobyla* algorithm in the *SciPy* `minimize` function, you will need to formulate the variable bounds as inequality constraints and contain them in the associated *constraints* parameter.

(source code excerpt)

```
// bounds set to anything else than None yields warning
if meth is 'cobyla' and bounds is not None:
    warn('Method %s cannot handle bounds.' % method,
         RuntimeWarning)
...
// No bounds argument in the internal call to the COBYLA function
elif meth == 'cobyla':
    return _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, **options)
```