# "scipy.optimize.minimize" How to force the coefficients to be not zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, minimize

I am trying to fit a function `p` which depends on two variables `x`,`T`. The data for the `p`,`T`,`x` are provided via an excel sheet with `pandas`. The following code works quite well.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./DataTest.xlsx"))
df = df.sort_values('x')

T = np.array(df['T'], dtype=float)
x = np.array(df['x'], dtype=float)
p = np.array(df['p'], dtype=float)
p0 = 67.17

def cav2(pars, T, x): # function p(T,x)
    a,b,c,d,e,f = pars
    return x * p0 + x * (1 - x) * (a + b * T + c * T ** 2 + d * x + e * x * T + f * x * T ** 2) * p0

def resid(pars, T, x):
    return ((p - cav2(pars, T, x)) ** 2).sum()

def constr(pars):
    return np.gradient(cav2(pars, T, x))

con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constr}
pars0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype=float)
res = minimize(resid, pars0, args=(T, x), method='cobyla', options={'maxiter': 50000}, constraints=con1)

print("a = %f , b = %f, c = %f, d = %f, e = %f, f = %f" % (res.x[0], res.x[1], res.x[2], res.x[3], res.x[4], res.x[5]))
```

The last `print`gives me the coefficients of my function:

```
a = 2.891584 , b = 0.000000, c = -0.000000, d = 0.792256, e = -0.000000, f = 0.000000
```

That brings me to my actual problem. Because some of the coefficients become zero, it makes the function `p(T,x)` independent from `T`, which i do not want. To be clear, at the moment `cav2(res.x, 300, 0.1)` gives the same result as for example `cav2(res.x, 500, 0.1)`.

Is there an (easy) way in `scipy.optimize.minimize` to force all of the coefficients to accept a value greater than zero ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a range of values you wish to bound `T` or `x` over? If so, specifying this may produce a local minimum with non-zero coefficients.

Comment: Actualy I don't realy understand how bounds work.  If I have something like this `bnds = ((1, 0.1, 1),(300, 1, 67))` and `bounds=bnds` in the `minimize` line. Does this stand for `bnds = ((Tmin, xmin, pmin),(Tmax, xmax, pmax))` ? If so it unfortunately does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some optimizer support bound constraint (e.g. L-BFGS-B) on coefficients.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np

T = np.random.normal(10)
x = np.random.normal(10)

p0 = 67.17

# Fake true parameters
a, b, c, d, e, f = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=6)

# targets
p = x * p0 + x * (1 - x) * (a + b * T + c * T ** 2 + d * x + e * x * T + f * x * T ** 2) * p0


def cav2(pars, T, x): # function p(T,x)
    a, b, c, d, e, f = pars
    return x * p0 + x * (1 - x) * (a + b * T + c * T ** 2 + d * x + e * x * T + f * x * T ** 2) * p0


def resid(pars, T, x):
    return ((p - cav2(pars, T, x)) ** 2).sum()


def constr(pars):
    return np.gradient(cav2(pars, T, x))

# this will force all parameters to be positive
bounds = [(0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None)]
pars0 = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1], dtype=float)

res = minimize(resid, pars0, args=(T, x), method='L-BFGS-B', options={'maxiter': 50000}, bounds=bounds)

print("a = %f , b = %f, c = %f, d = %f, e = %f, f = %f" % (res.x[0], res.x[1], res.x[2], res.x[3], res.x[4], res.x[5]))
```

The way the bounds works is `(lower, upper)` and putting `None` means no bound is applied. So if you don't want a bound on the first parameter, for example, you can replace bounds with:

```
[(None, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None), (0, None)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution with `method='L-BFGS-B'` works in way but unfortunately the method does not support constraints, which I need for my condition where the derivation of the function is positive everywhere (see `def constr()`). On the other hand the 'method='cobyla'` does not support bounds. =(

Comment: But you gave me a good hint to look how to formulate bounds as constraints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781622/does-scipys-minimize-function-with-method-cobyla-accept-bounds So thanks for that!